# Why does explicit narrowing not work, but implicit narrowing does

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Trying to figure out this weird behaviour in TypeScript:

```js
export function isArray(value?: any): value is any[] {
    return Array.isArray(value)
}
// value is any[] makes this work
const a: unknown = []
if (isArray(a)) {
    const l: number = a.length
}
// however it causes this to fail
const t: true = isArray([]) // Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'true'.ts(2322)
```

```
export function isArray(value: any[]): true
export function isArray(value?: any): false
export function isArray(value?: any): boolean {
    return Array.isArray(value)
}
// causes this to fail
const a: unknown = []
if (isArray(a)) {
    const l: number = a.length // 'a' is of type 'unknown'.ts(18046)
}
// but causes this to work
const t: true = isArray([])
```

Is there any way to have the best of both worlds? Where this works:

```js
const a: unknown = []
if (isArray(a)) {
    const l: number = a.length
}
const t: true = isArray([])
```

The use of `unknown` simplifies the actual use case of a function that checks if the argument is an array, if so do array things, otherwise if the argument is a map, do map things, otherwise and so on.

Comment: What you are looking for is Type Predicate: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

Comment: @EricMORAND type predicate is the first example, which fails on `const t: true = isArray([])`

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WyQd2W) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz perfect, [a little modification and false is working too!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABDAzgQQE4YIYE8AUAbtgDYgCmAXItmLgNoC6AlNVBhQFCiSwLLoseIqQoB+agHkAtjCgAeWg0YAaGnQB8rRMFIpy3cNHhJUmHAWJlyE9bm1WKAu00O8TA88Mc3qS7QBGcHAk5LSIAN6ciIgY5FAgGEheuAB0ZkKWouTMnAC+nBAIKFA01OAA1mBwAO5IALyIrjDAiPgZFvjYzMyRnACQRWAliCTUYCDSAeQYiI3YqaFgAOZQABb5iOQk+n39APT7iEMjJHM0i+Qr64iHWwAeAA7k0NQA5NhvznCtULjPiDelWqdTeqXwAEYABwABgALAA2XIFE6lKBsDjkc4dYRMXKonQQ6i6HZYxo4gj44qlYAAJmJejJnky+A+b2YQA) Please submit as an answer.

Comment: No, `Omit` doesn't mean what you think it means, and `Exclude<any[], any>` would not work either.  TS has no negated types.  Try `isArray(Math.random() < 0.5 ? "abc" : [])` and see that your version gives `false`, which is not what you want.  The closest you can get to `not any[]` is something more like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WzQl1m).  I could write that up but I don't see this requirement in your question or a use case in your [mre].  Should I proceed with my existing answer and not worry about false? Or do you want to [edit] to clarify your needs?  Let me know.

Comment: @jcalz good point, let me think about it

Comment: @jcalz thank to you, was able to come up with typechecker v9 that supports narrowing [index file](https://github.com/bevry/typechecker/blob/3ea794d71d08da87fe1962ec8557106fb87d0027/source/index.ts), [tests section](https://github.com/bevry/typechecker/blob/3ea794d71d08da87fe1962ec8557106fb87d0027/source/test.ts#L348), which will allow me to port [eachr](https://github.com/bevry/eachr) to typescript

Comment: Great! Now, what shall we do with this Stack Overflow question? Do you want to [edit] it with use cases that care about `false`? Or leave it alone and I’ll post an answer to the question as asked?